# Yii Framework - render CActiveForm without the form tag

Tags: html, ajax, forms, yii

In my next application, I want to dynamically load CActiveForms into other CActiveForms with AJAX.

Therefore, I create different form views like this:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', [...]
```

But it always renders the  tag. This results in nested forms:

```
<form id="form1">
    <form id="form2">
    </form>
</form>
```

How do i prevent the CActiveForm from rendering the form tag for form2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible natively with `CActiveForm`s. You could however create your own widget which inherits from it. Then you can override the `init()` and `run()` methods, and take out the `echo CHtml::endForm();` on line 340 and `echo CHtml::beginForm` on line 328.

Your results may be mixed though, a lot of Javascript and styling etc. relying on having a parent form with some settings etc.

Comment: Ok, it worked. I will see, how JavaScript and Css will work with that.

Comment: Glad it worked out. If it's a very specific case, you may be OK but I wouldn't use this too widely. Hope it works for you.

Comment: the other solution is to render the forms below each other and when you submit, you submit each form in a specific order. gonna try both versions.